# E11000 duplicate key error collection: Inserting document in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am seeding my database for testing so I have inserted 15000 instructor data in database now for each instructor I want to insert 100 course. so I ran to for loop 
first to get all instructor ids and second to store 100 course for that id of instructor but while inserting courses I get this type of error

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: Courser.courses index: ratings.user_1 dup key: { : null }
```

Here is the code to enter course for each instructor

```
seedCourse: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const instructors = await Instructor.find();
        //const insrtuctor contains 15000 instructor
        for(let oneInst of instructors) {
            for(let i=0; i<=100; i++) {
                const course = await new Course({
                    title: faker.lorem.sentence(),
                    description: faker.lorem.paragraph(),
                    author: oneInst._id,
                    prise: Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 4),
                    isPublished: 'true',
                    tags: ["java", "Nodejs", "javascript"]
                });
            const result = await course.save();
            await Instructor.findByIdAndUpdate(oneInst._id, { $push: { courses: result._id } });
            console.log(`Instructor Id ${oneInst._id} Course added ${i}`);
        }             
    } 
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

My course model definition looks something like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Course = mongoose.model('courses', new mongoose.Schema({

title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 3
},
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'instructor'
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5
},
ratings: [{
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
    }
}],
tags: [String],
rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    default: 0
},
ratedBy: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    default: 0
},
prise: {
    type: Number,
    required: function() { this.isPublished },
    min: 0
},
isPublished: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
}
}));

module.exports = Course;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Course schema `user` in `ratings` array is an unique field. You are not giving any unique value while storing course in DB. First time it tool value as null but next time it is trying to save null value for user. Hence violating the schema.
Either remove `unique:true` or pass an unique value for user